# Automator permissions error when running AppleScript in Safari – Alternatives and security risks?

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, automator

I want to use Automator and AppleScript to fill out a form in Safari. I have a functioning script that looks something like this toy example:

```
on run {}
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "Hello"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke tab
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "World"
end run
```

I wish to execute it with a keyboard shortcut when I'm at a specific point in my browser. However, when I do this, I run into permission issues:

```
The action "Run AppleSCript" encountered an error: 
"System Events got an error: Automator Workflow Runner 
(WorkflowServiceRunner, my_script_name) is not allowed to send keystrokes"
```

In `System Prefrences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Accessibility` I have allowed both `Automator` and `AppleScript Utility`, and under the  `Automation` tab, I have allowed `System Events` for Safari.

I can get it to work, at least temporary, if I allow Safari in `Accessibility` too, but that seems to be *too drastic and a security risk* to have Safari to always have full control just to run a script from time to time.

How should I approach this? I want the script to be easy to use, and wouldn't want to go into the settings each time to temporary allow Safari. Or can this be automated too? Is there a completely different approach than Automator and AppleScript that would allow me to do this in a more user friendly and safe way? Basically, I want to do something similar to what AutoHotKey would be able to do in Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m guessing that what you’ve done is set up a Quick Action and then given that Quick Action a shortcut under “Services” in “Keyboard:Shortcuts” in System Preferences. I was able to duplicate the problem by doing that: attempting to run the script requires that Safari itself have access to “control your computer”. If that is *not* what you’ve done, this solution should still work, but you may also want to update your question, in case a better solution is available.

What you can do is use redirection. Create an application that can be given permission to control your computer, and then create a Service that will launch the application.

1. Use Automator (or Script Editor) to create an Application with the above steps, adding as the first step `tell application "Safari" to activate`. You need that step because opening the app will take the focus away from Safari.

[image: First, create the application with the steps you want performed.]

2. Save this Application. (If using Automator, you tell Automator that it’s an application when you start creating the script; if using Script Editor, you tell Script Editor that it’s an application when you save the script.)
3. Use Automator to create a Quick Action. Give it the action “Launch Application” and tell it to launch the application you just created.

[image: Create a Service to launch the application.]

4. Drag the application you created in step 2 into the “Accessibility” list in System Preferences’s “Security & Privacy” settings. (You may have to unlock those settings to allow changes.) It should be checked automatically when you drag it in, but if not you can check it.

[image: Add it to the accessibility list by dragging and dropping.]

5. In the “Services” list in the “Keyboard:Shortcuts” settings of System Preferences, the Quick Action you created in step 3 should be listed. Give it a keyboard shortcut.

[image: And give it a keyboard shortcut.]

At this point, you should be able to use the keyboard shortcut to run the application, and only that application needs to have permission to control your computer.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer, and your assumption is right. I'm new to Automator and it seems I omitted some essential details. Just one question, if the use has several Safari windows open, is there a risk that 'activate' command will mess up? I assume that the user has the correct tab/window open when running the command

Comment: Not for this purpose. Activate is just like tabbing back to Safari after tabbing out. Safari remains in whatever state it was when left (possibly barring a JavaScript that does something on loss of focus). Since in this case the only reason Safari lost focus is that the keystroke started a new application, refocusing to Safari will return to it in with the same top window and the selection in the same place.

Comment: Excellent. Got it working, thank you. At the end I had to add both the application and the quick-action to the 'Accessibility' list, otherwise it was just as described. Oh, and if somebody in my situation gets a signing-error saving the application, you need to follow these instructions: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a